# Full Text Search in SQL 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

When I attempt to search in the full-text catalog which is my created earlier, I haven't been finding any word within database.

For example:

```
My word: Where
CONTAINSTABLE(TABLO,*,' "*Where*" ')
```

Here is no problem.

But,

```
CONTAINSTABLE(TABLO,*,' "*here*" ')
```

if I wrote a thing like above the line,no rows returning.What should I do?

Comment: Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that full text search will match based on the back end of the word being passed in.  You could have it match "Wher*" but not "*here".  This is called prefix matching.

> < prefix term> ::= {"word*" | "phrase*" }

Trying to match based on "*here" would be a VERY expensive match for the full text engine to do.